# Merging three tables based on columns

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I've 3 tables in SAS having a 1000 column that I want to merge together as

```
table_a
obj_Id | value1a | value2a .... | value1000a 
 1     |    T1   |    T1        |    T1
 2     |    T1   |    T1        |    T1
 3     |    T1   |    T1        |    T1
```

```
table_b
obj_Id | value1b | value2b .... | value1000b 
 1     |    T2   |    T2        |    T2
 2     |    T2   |    T2        |    T2
 3     |    T2   |    T2        |    T2
```

```
table_c
obj_Id  | value1c  | value2c ....    | value1000c
 1     |    T3   |    T3             |    T3
 2     |    T3   |    T3             |    T3
 3     |    T3   |    T3             |    T3
```

I want to get table d as below.

```
table_d
obj_Id | value1a | value1b | value1c     | value2a |value2b |  value2c    ....| value1000c
 1     |    T1   |    T1   |    T1       |    T2   |    T2  |    T2           |    T3
 2     |    T1   |    T1   |    T1       |    T2   |    T2  |    T2           |    T3
 3     |    T1   |    T1   |    T1       |    T2   |    T2  |    T2           |    T3
```

I've messed around with SAS merge statements and proc_sql
Is there any way to do it using %MACRO?

Comment: You need to explain in what way MERGE did not do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use plain sql, you can use a [CREATE TABLE AS STATEMENT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php), with something like

```
CREATE TABLE table_d AS (
  SELECT * FROM table_a a
  JOIN table_b b on a.obj_Id = b.obj_Id
  JOIN table_c c on a.obj_Id = c.obj_Id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have a unique identifier and no other common variables you can just merge the datasets.

```
data table_d;
  merge table_a table_b table_c;
  by obj_Id ;
runl
```

Make sure the datasets are sorted by obj_Id .